# Why ins't it possible to create a list with multiple arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x

I got curious about why we can do this:

```
l = [1,2,3,4]
```

But get an error when trying this:

```
l = list(1,2,3,4)
```

Also, as most of people usually suggest, despite of passing the arguments of the latter as a tuple solves the problem, why this doesn't work either?

```
t = tuple(1,2,3,4)
```

Comment: Why should it? `list()` *converts* an existing sequence to a list. Use `[..]` to produce a list from a fixed number of elements instead. If `list()` took the same style of inputs, then why have two different syntaxes at all?

Comment: `list` at the moment takes an iterable or a sequence as an input. Create your own list that does so `def my_list(*args): return [*args]`

Comment: @BhargavRao: `return list(args)`.. Convert the tuple to a list.

Comment: @MartijnPieters `list()` *converts* any kind of iterable, not only sequences. Having only one way to do each thing is a pythonic, he may not know that if he comes from another language.

Comment: @Adirio: I was simplifying; see my answer below where I use the term *iterable*.

Comment: @BhargavRao a sequence is by definition an iterable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`list()` and `tuple()` are used to *convert* a different type of object into a list or tuple, respectively. Any iterable will do there. The two functions are not intended to create an object from a discreet number of inputs, that's what the literal notations are for.

So if you have a fixed number of elements, each produceable with an expression, the right way to create a list is to use the `[...]` literal syntax. If you have a variable number of elements produced by a single iterable object, use `list()`. The two use-cases differ.

If `list()` accepted multiple arguments, then you wouldn't need to have the `[...]` syntax anymore; there is no point in having two different syntaxes fill the same use case.

Comment: That makes sense. I haven't realized that. Thank you.